# Specify the first day of the following month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to specify the first day of the following month.

For example, I want my app to say: "Your order will be shipped on February 1, 2012" assuming we're in January.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This way:

```
 Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.next_month
 => Wed, 01 Feb 2012
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.
How can I specify the format to be like the following:
Wednesday, February 1, 2012.

I see that `to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)` includes everything but the day name.

Answer (score 1):

Or, with vanilla Ruby without ActiveSupport (1.9.3 in this case)

```
t = Time.now
Date.new(t.year, t.month).next_month
```